# Find entryno set from multiple set of records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two SQL temp tables `#Temp1` and `#Temp2`.

I want to get `entryno` which contain set of temp table two.

For example: `#Temp2` has 8 records. I want to search in `#Temp1` which contains a set of records from `#Temp1`.

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp1 (entryNo INT, setid INT, measurid INT,measurvalueid int)

CREATE TABLE #Temp2(setid INT, measurid INT,measurvalueid int)

INSERT INTO #Temp1 (entryNo,setid,measurid,measurvalueid ) 

VALUES  (1,400001,1,1),                                                        
        (1,400001,2,110),
        (1,400001,3,1001),
        (1,400001,4,1100),
        (2,400002,5,100),
        (2,400002,6,102),
        (2,400002,7,1003),
        (2,400002,8,10004),
        (3,400001,1,1),
        (3,400001,2,110),
        (3,400001,3,1001),
        (3,400001,4,1200)

INSERT INTO #Temp2 (setid,measurid,measurvalueid ) 

    VALUES (400001,1,1),
           (400001,2,110),
           (400001,3,1001),
           (400001,4,1100),
           (400002,5,100),
           (400002,6,102),
           (400002,7,1003),
           (400002,8,10004)
```

I want output

```
EntryNo
   1
   2
```

It contains two sets.

One is:

```
  (400001,1,1),
  (400001,2,110),
  (400001,3,1001),
  (400001,4,1100)
```

The second is:

```
  (400002,5,100),
  (400002,6,102),
  (400002,7,1003),
  (400002,8,10004)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH DataSourceInialData AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [entryNo], [setid]) AS [GroupCount]
    FROM #Temp1
), DataSourceFilteringData AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [setid]) AS [GroupCount]
    FROM #Temp2
)
SELECT A.[entryNo]
FROM DataSourceInialData A
INNER JOIN DataSourceFilteringData B
    ON A.[setid] = B.[setid]
    AND A.[measurid] = B.[measurid]
    AND A.[measurvalueid] = B.[measurvalueid]
    -- we are interested in groups which are passed completely by the filtering groups
    AND A.[GroupCount] = B.[GroupCount]
GROUP BY A.[entryNo]
-- aftering joining the rows, the filtered rows must match the filtering rows
HAVING COUNT(A.[setid]) = MAX(B.[GroupCount]);
```

The algorithm is simple:

1. we count how many rows exists per data group
2. we count how many rows exists per filtering group
3. we join the initial data and the filtering data
4. after the join we count how many rows are left in the initial data and if there count is equal to the filtering count for the given group

and the result is:

[image]

Note, that I am checking for each match. For example, if in your sample data, there is one more row for `entryNo = 1` it won't be included in the result. In order to change this behavior, comment this row:

```
-- we are interested in groups which are passed completely by the filtering groups
AND A.[GroupCount] = B.[GroupCount]
```